# Three.js Ray.intersectObjects not respecting parent Object3D rotation

Tags: three.js

I am having trouble using Ray.intersectObjects within a hierarchy of Object3D transforms.  Essentially, intersectObjects seems to be ignoring the rotation at the top level of the hierarchy.  I have tried to reproduce this problem by modifying the webgl_interactive_cubes.html demo, with no luck.  Unfortunately I can't post what I'm working on.  I am going to try to reproduce the problem so I can share it, but maybe somebody has a suggestion for what's wrong.  This is using THREE.js r52.

Here are what I believe to be the relevant pieces:

> - I have a root THREE.Object3D element that holds a top-level rotation.  This is the rotation that seems to be ignored.
> - This root element has two children, both THREE.Object3D objects.  They each have a (fixed) rotation and position transformation.
> - I am looking for intersections among the children of these two elements.  These children are all clones of THREE.Mesh objects from another heirarchy, created using THREE.Mesh.clone().
> - When the top-level rotation is zeroed out, the intersections all work perfectly.
> - As soon as a top-level rotation is applied, the intersections act as though there were no rotation... the object moves on the screen, but I get intersections returned as though the object had not moved.

I have tried calling updateMatrixWorld(true) on the root before checking for intersections, but that makes no difference.

Comment: Actually, after playing around a bit more with it, it seems more like the rotation on the root is being applied in reverse... if I rotate down, the intersection target seems to move up, and vice versa

Comment: This should work. If you continue to have problems, please post a simple live jsfiddle example.